# How to retrieve the geographic origin of the samples referenced/deposited in genBank using R?

Tags: r, gis, genbank

A simple question: how to retrieve the geographic origin of samples referenced/deposited in genBank using R?

Best and thanks!

Pedro

Comment: Welcom to SO--please post your data (or a sample of it) in a format that we can work with easily and what you've tried so far.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Well, I am very sorry to say that I have no reproducible example, simply because I have no idea about how to do this. I need, for example, to get all the cyt-b sequences available in the genBank for Canis familiaris with their associated geographic locality. Sorry and thank you